# Maven shade plugin configuration not replacing the package

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

Based on the requirement at [Maven dependency incompatible library class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60396734), I have tried shade plugin as like below, but went in vain.

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <filters>
                <filter>
                    <artifact>com.lib:Encoder</artifact>
                    <includes>
                        <include>x/y/z/**</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>a/b/c/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </filter>
            </filters>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

My target here is to replace the package with of a.b.c structure with x.y.z of classes.
Did I miss any crucial configurations here?

Comment: Check the documentation https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#relocations

Answer (score 1):

To replace the package **a.b.c** with **x.y.z** on your shaded jar you should add the **relocations** entry as follow on maven-shade-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                <relocations>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>x.y.z</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>a.b.c</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                </relocations>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Still facing same failure. Also, I have tried the <phase> with 'install' as well. No luck yet!

Comment: What kind of failure are you facing? Can you share details?

Comment: /cannot access a.b.c.Template
[ERROR]   class file for a.b.c.Template not found

Comment: it is for - mvn install